# Plot surface from grouped data

Tags: matlab, plot

I imported text into a **matrix**. What I need is to plot this as a surface

```
1,1,1
1,2,3
1,3,2
2,1,4
2,4,6
3,1,2
3,2,1
3,4,2
...
```

How do I transform the imported matrix into something which can be used for the *surf*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`scatter3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) if indeed you have the 3 coordinates x,y,z...

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `surf`, you'll need to interpolate your scattered data onto a regular grid. Try using `meshgrid` to generate a regular grid in your independent coordinates x and y, then use `TriScatteredInterp` to interpolate your dependent z data onto your regular grid. This interpolated data can then be used with `surf'.

Comment: may be i did something wrong but meshgrid said - too much data. i have 200K items in each vector (x,y,z)